# Serve Google Functions from Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to achieve the following configuration:

0. https://example.com - serve Google Cloud Storage BacketA
1. https://example.com/files/* - serve Google Cloud Storage BacketB
2. https://example.com/api/* - serve google functions -> `https://us-central1-{my-app-name}.cloudfunctions.net/api`

I have an issue with step 2. How to specify backend as cloud functions endpoint? How to point to google function in backend configuration?

How I can do that?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Indicate us what problem you are facing with step 2.

Comment: How to specify backend as cloudfunctions endpoint? How to point to google function in backend configuration?

Comment: @DioNNiS you question is not clear, do you want to use your custom domain instead of the autogenerate cloud function endpoint domain?

Comment: @andresmijares Yes, I want to map cloud function endpoint to the path of my domain.

Comment: why don't you use a different domain such as `functions.example.com` to solve this issue? https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-setup-custom-domain

Comment: @Juancki, different subdomain - it will be CORS with extra OPTION request, which affecting performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your domain with your firebase project,

these two articles should get you on the right foot:

- [Functions overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)
- [Serverless Overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview)

You need to go to Hosting, after getting started, it will provide you a way to attach your custom domain to your project, you will need to validate the domain, last time I made it, it took 72 hours; the steps needed can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

All the information you need is there.

Comment: this is what I currently have.
I can not use Firebase hosting to map path to Google Storage.
As I understand for that, I need Google Cloud load balancer with CDN... =(